# Facing issue while creating user through keycloak

Tags: jboss, resteasy, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to create users in keycloak through java web application and below is the code that I am using:

```
    Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance("http://localhost:8080/auth/", "realm", "username", "password", "Client");

    CredentialRepresentation credential = new CredentialRepresentation();
    credential.setType(CredentialRepresentation.PASSWORD);
    credential.setValue("test123");
    UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
    user.setUsername("testuser");
    user.setFirstName("Test");
    user.setLastName("User");
    user.setCredentials(Arrays.asList(credential));
    kc.realm("demo").users().create(user);
```

I have added the below dependencies my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-m07</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>

    </dependency>
```

and below entries in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/auth</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/auth/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and I have also created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml with the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" export="true"
                meta-inf="export" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"
                export="true" meta-inf="export" slot="main" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" services="export" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am getting the below error:

```
10:56:39,428 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) Failed to define class org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder in Module "deployment.Test.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ResteasyClientBuilder (Module "deployment.Test.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:52) [keycloak-admin-client-3.0.0.Final.jar:3.0.0.Final]
       at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.getInstance(Keycloak.java:78) [keycloak-admin-client-3.0.0.Final.jar:3.0.0.Final]
       at com.test.ui.login.controller.KeycloakLoginActionController.initialize(KeycloakLoginActionController.java:86) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.controller.KeycloakLoginActionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initialize(KeycloakLoginActionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.bean.KeycloakLoginBean.initialize(KeycloakLoginBean.java:31) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.bean.KeycloakLoginBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initialize(KeycloakLoginBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.33.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.33.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.33.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.33.Final-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2526) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2166) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2111) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:293) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AuthenticatedActionsValve.java:68) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-3.3.0.CR2.jar:3.3.0.CR2]
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:185) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-3.3.0.CR2.jar:3.3.0.CR2]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder from [Module "deployment.Test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       ... 60 more

11:03:11,155 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/Test].[Faces Servlet]] (http-127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder from [Module "deployment.Test.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:361) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:482) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:277) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:92) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:568) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.7.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:52) [keycloak-admin-client-3.0.0.Final.jar:3.0.0.Final]
       at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.getInstance(Keycloak.java:78) [keycloak-admin-client-3.0.0.Final.jar:3.0.0.Final]
       at com.test.ui.login.controller.KeycloakLoginActionController.initialize(KeycloakLoginActionController.java:86) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.controller.KeycloakLoginActionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initialize(KeycloakLoginActionController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.bean.KeycloakLoginBean.initialize(KeycloakLoginBean.java:31) [classes:]
       at com.test.ui.login.bean.KeycloakLoginBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.initialize(KeycloakLoginBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java) [classes:]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-1.1.33.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.33.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.33.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.33.Final-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2526) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2166) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2111) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.as.weld.webtier.jsf.ForwardingApplication.publishEvent(ForwardingApplication.java:293) [jboss-as-weld-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP9-redhat-1]
       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.SP1-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AuthenticatedActionsValve.invoke(AuthenticatedActionsValve.java:68) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-3.3.0.CR2.jar:3.3.0.CR2]
       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:185) [keycloak-tomcat-core-adapter-3.3.0.CR2.jar:3.3.0.CR2]
       at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.7.Final-redhat-3.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-3]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.15.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.15.Final-redhat-1]
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

I see that keycloak is internally using RestEasy framework to call the rest api to create the user. Is it possible to redirect the keycloak to use com.sun.jersey to do this operation or if I am making any mistake in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to perform this task by migrating my application to JBoss EAP 7.0. Seems like something is missing in JBoss EAP 6.4.7 related to Keycloak dependency.